# current directory vs directory from which the application loaded

Tags: windows, dll

In the Microsoft documention the dll loading order is defined under the following link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order

If SafeDllSearchMode is disabled, the search order is as follows:

1. The directory from which the application loaded.
2. The current directory.
3. The system directory. Use the GetSystemDirectory function to get the path of this directory.
4. The 16-bit system directory. There is no function that obtains the path of this directory, but it is searched.
5. The Windows directory. Use the GetWindowsDirectory function to get the path of this directory.
6. The directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable. Note that this does not include the per-application path specified by the App Paths registry key. The App Paths key is not used when computing the DLL search path.

I don't understand the difference between

1. directory from which the application loaded
2. current directory

Let's say the application is installed in %programfiles% and I have a shortcut on the desktop to start it.
In that scenario what is "The directory from which the application loaded."?
The current directory must be the dektop, right?

Any clarification is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Start cmd.exe, the prompt you see indicates the current directory.  CD to change it.  For a program you start with a shortcut on the desktop it is specified by the shortcut properties, "Start in" setting.  It is only the same as the directory where the EXE is stored by accident, so something you never want to rely on.

Comment: The application directory is the location of the process executable. It's available as the dynamic environment variable `__APPDIR__`. The current directory is the process working directory. Initially it's either inherited from the working directory of the parent or set explicitly by the parent when it calls `CreateProcessW`. Subsequently an application can call `SetCurrentDirectoryW` to change the working directory.

Comment: I recommend either calling [`SetDefaultDllDirectories`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-setdefaultdlldirectories) or using [`LoadLibraryExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryexw) flags, e.g. `LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DEFAULT_DIRS`, and `AddDllDirectory` to construct the DLL search path for each call without the current directory or `PATH`.

Comment: Note that, unlike Unix `dlopen`, the presence of a slash or backslash in `lpLibFileName` (e.g. `L"spam\\eggs.dll"`) does not make a DLL path relative to the working directory. The loader resolves the path against every directory in the DLL search path, typically starting with the application directory, and if the current directory is removed from the search path to make it secure, chances are the DLL won't be found. If you need a path like that to be resolved relative to the working directory, resolve it manually via `GetFullPathNameW`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments basically answer your question, but let me answer it directly, and then provide examples.

1. The "directory from which the application loaded" is the directory that contains the .exe for the application. Note that the location of a shortcut doesn't affect this--the shortcut just points to the location of the .exe.
2. The "current directory" is, as @ErykSun mentioned, the process's working directory; it can change as the process runs (the developer can make a call to SetCurrentDirectory). The process's working directory will often start simply as the directory containing the .exe though.

   However, a shortcut can modify the initial working directory to be a directory other than that containing the .exe, using the shortcut property "Start in".

Here's an example:

1. Application shortcut exists in "C:\Users\Me\Desktop"
2. Application .exe exists in "C:\Program Files\App" - *This is the dir from which app loads*
3. Shortcut's "Start In" directory is specified as "C:\Users\Me\RunDir". - *This is the curr dir at process start*

Or a simpler situation:

1. Application .exe exists in "C:\Program Files\App" and you run it by simply opening it in that folder (either programmatically or through Windows GUI) - *At the time the process starts, both of the dirs in question refer to this dir*

**Services**

One common example of when these two directories are different is with services. A service that runs under the SYSTEM account will generally start the process from the "C:\Windows\System32" directory, while the application executable will generally reside in some other directory, e.g. within "C:\Program Files".